# NSPredicate crash with custom param

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I try to generate dynamically a string for NSPredicate

This work perfectly:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %K MATCHES[cd] %@", sKey, sLookForString];
```

But this crash with error "'Unable to parse the format string " %K %@[cd] %@"'"  :

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %K %@[cd] %@", sKey, @"MATCHES", sLookForString];
```

So, how to build a string with the "MATCHES" dynamic?

Comment: Use `stringWithFormat:` to _assemble_ the string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `predicateWithFormat:` won't let you form the *verb* dynamically (the syntax is quite clear about this). So form the verb dynamically as you form the predicate string beforehand. Something like this:

```
NSString* verb = @"MATCHES"; // or whatever the verb is to be
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" %%K %@[cd] %%@", verb];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:s, sKey, sLookForString];
```

Alternatively use `NSExpression` and `NSComparisonPredicate` (and, if necessary, `NSCompoundPredicate`) to form the predicate completely dynamically in code, without a format string. This is often a better way; `stringWithFormat:` is really just a convenience for the simplest cases. So for example:

```
NSExpression* eKey = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:sKey];
NSExpression* eLookForString = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:sLookForString];
NSPredicateOperatorType operator = NSMatchesPredicateOperatorType;
NSComparisonPredicateOptions opts =
    NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption | NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption;
NSPredicate* pred = 
    [NSComparisonPredicate 
        predicateWithLeftExpression:eKey 
        rightExpression:eLookForString 
        modifier:0 
        type:operator options:opts];
```